# Use form field value as reference to JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use an HTML form field's value to define what variable I use in a JavaScript function. I have a solution but I think there's a more elegant way to do it.

I have two arrays of names, male and female, and my HTML form has a set of two radio buttons for male and female. On submit, I do this:

```
gender = $("#gender input:checked").val(); //get value of checked button
if (gender == "male" ) {
    name = male[Math.floor(Math.random()*male.length)];
} else {
    name = female[Math.floor(Math.random()*female.length)];
}
$("#result").html(name);
```

My solution is an if-else but I wondered if something can convert the gender value into a reference to the variable of the same name. Then I could replace the if-else with something like this:

```
name = gender[Math.floor(Math.random()*gender.length)];
```

I'd be curious to hear what you think. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put the genders into an object:

```
var genderData = {
   male: [ ... ]
   female: [ ... ]
}
```

And then use the following syntax:

```
genderData[gender][Math.floor(Math.random() * genderData[gender].length)]
```

You can also simplify it a bit to make things more readable:

```
var gd = genderData[gender];
name = gd[Math.floor(Math.random() * gd.length)];
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked well. The key was applying the field value as an object property name. Looks good.

Answer (score 0):

If `male`/`female` are global variables then they can be found in the `window` object. In this case you should be able to use something like

```
name = window[gender][Math.floor(Math.random() * window[gender].length)];
```

where `gender` must be a valid variable name. However, I discourage you from using global variables. Instead use a local object with the properties `male` and `female`.